# Hide file from traceback

Tags: python, traceback

I have this **try/except**:

```
try:
    return dispatcher.dispatch(path, method, params)
except Exception as expt:
    webApp.logger.error(str(expt))
    raise ValueError('Imposible conectarse')
```

And let's say that, for example, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leandro/.virtualenvs/DesktopProxyV2/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/wsgi.py", line 389, in handle_one_response
    result = self.application(self.environ, start_response)
  File "/home/leandro/Desarrollo/desktop_proxy/modulos/proxy/webproxy.py", line 60, in request_handler
    raise ValueError('Imposible conectarse')
ValueError: Imposible conectarse
```

Is there a way to show or customize it like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wsgi.py", line 389, in handle_one_response
    result = self.application(self.environ, start_response)
  File "webproxy.py", line 60, in request_handler
    raise ValueError('Imposible conectarse')
```

Without it showing the file route?

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot tweak the Python interpreter's output you can **mimic** it using the [traceback module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html).

You can wrap your entire application in a try..except statement and print out your own messages from there.

The [`traceback.format_exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html#traceback.format_exc) function will give you a multiline string that you can then modify and print to suit your needs.

```
def main():
    #Your application code

if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main()
    except BaseException:
        lines = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            print re.sub(r'File ".*[\\/]([^\\/]+.py)"', r'File "\1"', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so straightforward but you can use [traceback](https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) module to filter out the traceback.

```
try:
    # something which throws
except Exception as expt:
    import traceback
    trace_lines = traceback.format.exc().splitlines()
    # tracelines contains all the lines from the traceback
    # Accordingly filter for e.g. check for lines containing File and then extract only the filename from the complete path and print it
```

For e.g. `trace_lines[0]` will be `Traceback (most recent call last):`

I tried this:

```
try:
    a = 1/0
except Exception as e:
    lines = traceback.format_exc().splitlines()
    print (lines)
```

This prints:

```
['Traceback (most recent call last):', '  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>', 'ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero']
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham - I updated the answer with a minimal example. Why do think it doesn't work?

Comment: you need to raise the error, the OP is not catching an exception. Look at the expected output